# How to draw 2D shapes with live x and y data with javascript on svg or canvas

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, 2d, draw

I am getting a data from a waterjet machine that is cutting some steel products and I would like to draw what it is cutting in real time. I am getting data for X, Y and Z coordinates. So i would like to show the process of drawing the shape of a product with X and Y. And on the side I just want to show Z as a bar with moving pin either up or down like this: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Le5y61rj/1/)

I was able to draw, but unfortunately my drawing starts from zero coordinates and it is just drawing lines, How can i make continuous drawing without going back to 0 0 coordinates:

```
   <svg id="svg" height="700" width="600">
                        <polyline id="polyline-id" points="" style="fill:none; stroke: white; stroke-width: 3"></polyline>
   </svg>
```

this is how i get and draw:

```
socket.on('data', function (data) {

    const arr = data.split("|").slice(1);
    let dataSet = {};
    arr.map((o, i) => {
        if ((i + 1) % 2 != 0) dataSet[o] = arr[i + 1];
    });
    console.log(dataSet);

    var svg = document.getElementById("svg");
    var point = svg.createSVGPoint();
    point.x = dataSet.Xact/2;
    point.y = dataSet.Yact/2;
    var polyline = document.getElementById("polyline-id");
    polyline.points.appendItem(point);
});
```

this is how my data looks on console:

```
{power: "ON", mode: "MANUAL", execution: "READY", Xact: "0.00", Yact: "0.00", …}
Block: "0"
Xact: "2966.04"
Xcom: "0.00"
Yact: "44.15"
Ycom: "0.00"
Zact: "-17.97"
Zcom: "0.00"
execution: "READY"
line: "0"
mode: "MANUAL"
path_feedrate: "0.00"
power: "ON"
program: "37211 S75 JET - 1.003_imported_CNC.ORD↵"
```

I can't fix my issue. What am I doing wrong? Or are there any libraries for implementing my project?